# Access a Redis key by pointer

Tags: redis

I was wondering if there is anyway to access a Redis key using a pointer. As far as I know, accessing a Redis key will require some operations like hashing. I know hashing algorithm is n(1) but is there anyway to access a key faster? like keeping the key's pointer and pass the pointer instead of key name to the Redis ...

Comment: n(1) is a constant complexity, can you explain a little more what you do you mean when you say faster way ?

Comment: @Doodle Well I am looking for a solution to share variables between some applications. Consume you have 2 Golang applications and want to share some variables between them. as far as i know, fastest way to access a is access-by-pointer ...

Comment: can't you directly provide the access of the redis database to the other application, exactly the way you access in application one, the other will also do the same. It's true that to share pointers are generally fast because they occupy a constant memory compared to variable size datatypes(i.e structures). But Here you will have to store the pointers as well that also adds a memory overhead

Comment: @Doodle Yeah you are right. I should have understood this. thanks for you time